# How to correctly combine multiple rowss into comma seperated string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the `STUFF` function to combine multiple rows of data into a comma separated string.

Here is what I have done

```
SELECT 
 s.Id
,s.Name
,STUFF(
(
    SELECT 
    c.Name
    FROM [Groups] AS c
    INNER JOIN [GroupToUser] AS stc ON stc.CategoryId = c.Id
    WHERE stc.StageId = s.Id
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') AS GroupsTheUserBelongsTo 
FROM [Users] AS s
```

This is working somehow like expected. However, it is returning `XML` string missing the first character.

How can I make it return a comma separated string instead of XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to make sure you put the ',' comma in the query.  so ',' + c.Name.

```
SELECT 
 s.Id
,s.Name
,STUFF(
(
    SELECT

     ',' + c.Name

    FROM [Groups] AS c
    INNER JOIN [GroupToUser] AS stc ON stc.CategoryId = c.Id
    WHERE stc.StageId = s.Id
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') AS GroupsTheUserBelongsTo 
FROM [Users] AS s
```

So to explain what is happening for you. you have a standard query that you then tell sql-server to turn into XML but without a root element and because there is no column name it will also be without tags.  When you add the comma or other delimiter it will put a comma between each row.  STUFF(xmlstring,1,1,'') says take the in the first position of the string take out the character that is there and put in 1 occurrence of '' which basically is the same as removing the leading comma.

here is a little example to break it down into pieces to better understand what is going on.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Col VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C')

DECLARE @Values AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Values = (
SELECT
    ',' + Col
FROM
    @Table
FOR XML PATH (''))

SELECT @Values

SELECT STUFF(@Values,1,1,'')
```

@DanGuzman makes a good point that if you are worried about special characters in your Names column becoming encoded/replace and xml encoding remaining in your string you can try:

```
SELECT 
     s.Id
    ,s.Name
    ,STUFF( (
       SELECT
          ',' + c.Name

       FROM [Groups] AS c
       INNER JOIN [GroupToUser] AS stc ON stc.CategoryId = c.Id
       WHERE stc.StageId = s.Id
       FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)')
       ,1,1,'') AS GroupsTheUserBelongsTo 
FROM
    [Users] AS s
```

Comment: @Jaylen yes it added a delimiter so that your string would actually be a comma delimited string.  As far as XML the datatype should be a character datatype NOT XML but you can also specifically cast it back to VARCHAR(MAX) or whatever you want as well if you are not getting your expected datatype. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: Note the result will contain XML entity references instead of the original character (e.g. "&amp;" instead of "&") to escape certain characters unless  `TYPE` is specified along with the `value` method: `FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')`.